# Using double quotes and variables in sed command

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have two bash variables, one called GREP_ENTRY, which contains a long string:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto spectre_v2=retpoline rd.lvm.lv=d6c-2b-59-93-97-ea/lv_root rhgb quiet console=tty0`

and the other is called NEW_ENTRY, which is the exact same as GREP_ENTRY but with **fips=1** appended to the end:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto spectre_v2=retpoline rd.lvm.lv=d6c-2b-59-93-97-ea/lv_root rhgb quiet console=tty0 fips=1`

I am trying to use sed to find **GREP_ENTRY** in */etc/default/grub* and replace it with NEW_ENTRY. Currently, I am trying to use double quotes as follows:

`sed -i "s/$GREP_ENTRY/$NEW_ENTRY/g" /etc/default/grub`

But I get the error:

`` sed: -e expression #1, char 123: unknown option to `s' ``

I have tried using other combinations of double quotes but to no avail. Can someone explain how I can properly use sed in this situation?

Comment: Why not just `sed "/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/s|^.*$|$NEW_ENTRY|" /etc/default/grub`? (add `-i` or `-i.bak` to edit in place, and/or create backup)

Answer (score 2):

Both variables contain `/`. That confuses sed's `s` command.

Switch from `s///` to `s|||`.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, I just tried sed -i "s|$GREP_ENTRY|$NEW_ENTRY|g" /etc/default/grub and it worked